# how to identify static assets from an HTML

Tags: html, static-files

I have been tasked with listing all static assets from a webpage. I understand that static assets are those file that never change at runtime.

Is there a systematic way to distinguish these from dynamic files?

If I have to list all the static assets. What would be the best starting point?

Comment: Static assets are things that don't change. On the web, these are things like JavaScript files, style sheets, and images. 

A good start could be, making a list of the extensions of those kinds of files and then make a string search in the HTML output.

Comment: The task formulation is not very clear. Do you mean 'all (static) objects that this page would cause to get loaded if viewed in a browser'? How do you get the page and can you read the content of the resources it refers to? Note there is no sure-fire way to determine if a given URI refers to a static or dynamic object, if all you got is HTTP access to the server. The server is not required to disclose how it produced the document. For any specific system, there may be enough clues to guess reliably, but no general method can possibly exist.

Comment: when you say " enough clues to guess reliably" it is exactly what I mean. I need to know what is the best way to determine all the static objects in an HTML accepting that in some instances this may not be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client's perspective, there is no systematic way to determine which part of an html response comes from a static file or is generated at runtime by the server. The html standard does not make that difference.

That being said, *most of the time* you can guess which part of the response comes from static files. When the html responds with links to files such as .css, .js, .gif and so on, there's a pretty good chance that that comes from a static file.

But determining which html element comes from a file on disk and which is built at runtime is not possible.

The systematic approach is to analyze the code that forms the html response, and determine from there which resource is static and which is dynamic.

**edit**
You added that you don't need to be 100%. If you don't need that, then maybe you can use [cloudflare's list of file extentions](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-Cloudflare-cache-for-static-content-). The reason cloudflare caches these extensions by default is that they are typically static.